# Why i have this error "StartTag: invalid element name"?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have this function in javascript

```
function validar(e) {
   const dia = (new Date(e.target.value)).getDay();
   if (dia <= 4) { //Cualquier día menor que Viernes
      e.target.value = ""; //Resetear la fecha
      alert("Fecha inválida"); //Dar feedback al usuario
   }

};
```

And this is my xml where i call the javascript functio

```
<div class="wrap-input3">
     <h3 class="contact3-form-subtitle">Fecha de pedido:</h3>
     <div>
     <input type="date" id="fecha_pedido" name="fecha_pedido" required="1" onchange="validar(event)" />
     </div>
</div>
```

Why the logs display this error
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: StartTag: invalid element name, line 43

Please i need some help

Comment: What is line 43?

Comment: Where my function "validar" start

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript contains `<=`, which is confusing the parsing of the surrounding XML.

Import your JavaScript from an external file to avoid the error.  Or, if you really want the JavaScript to be inline, wrap in CDATA so it's not parsed by XML interpreter:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
    function validar(e) {
       const dia = (new Date(e.target.value)).getDay();
       if (dia <= 4) { //Cualquier día menor que Viernes
          e.target.value = ""; //Resetear la fecha
          alert("Fecha inválida"); //Dar feedback al usuario
       }
    };
//]]>
</script>
```