# HTML - multiple parser errors : StartTag: invalid element name

Tags: javascript, html, formatting

I am trying to upload some code to a webpage I am helping to create and I keep getting these errors, referring to the JS part of my code. Any ideas how to fix it? I googled the problem but most answers are outdated or referring to PHP:

Entity: line 382: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
^
Entity: line 392: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name
for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
^
Entity: line 401: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name
for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
^
Entity: line 412: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {

Here's the relevant code:

```
filterSelection("allpapers")

function filterSelection(c) {
    var x, i;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
    if (c == "allpapers") c = "";
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
        if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
    }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
    var i, arr1, arr2;
    arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
    arr2 = name.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) { element.className += " " + arr2[i]; }
    }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
    var i, arr1, arr2;
    arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
    arr2 = name.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
            arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
        }
    }
    element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
        current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
        this.className += " active";
    });
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add in the relevant code segment (not a link).

Comment: So...have you considered [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66696841/why-i-have-this-error-starttag-invalid-element-name) ?

Comment: Maybe you need to wait for the page to initialize before looping through DOM elements?